# Parent container's height is not stretching for children?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have this HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

...and this CSS:

```
#container {
    border:1px #ff0000 solid;
    position:relative;
}

#container .child {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#f5f5f5;
    float:left;
}
```

Without using "float", does anyone know how to make #container's height stretch to collective height of all DIV's with class.child?

http://jsfiddle.net/TLxxR/

In case anyone is wondering why, I'm trying to center #container (like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TLxxR/1/) and using "float:left" for example removes the centering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#container {
    border:1px #ff0000 solid;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Adding overflow hidden will clear your floats

**edit**: adding overflow: auto also clears the float if you find that other elements are being cut off

Comment: Yup, that's the answer.

Comment: -1. Using `overflow: hidden` is bad practice simply for clearing floats. Elements may be cut off due to positioning, margins, or CSS3 transforms. It's much more reliable to go with a clearfix.

Comment: @BenM - can you give an example?

Comment: @BenM I would point to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best.
Both solutions are acceptable but you are right my method could cut off content that has been positioned with negative margins etc.

Comment: @Andrew sure. Check out this example using `overflow: hidden` > http://jsfiddle.net/TLxxR/6/ and then this one that uses a clearfix > http://jsfiddle.net/TLxxR/5/ (you'll need to use a WebKit browser to see what I mean).

Comment: This one uses `overflow: auto` and causes scrollbars: http://jsfiddle.net/TLxxR/7/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a clearfix:

```
#container:after {
   display: table;
   content: '';
   clear: both;
}
```

The complexity of them will depend on the browsers your application needs to support, but the above should get you started.

[Here's a great article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) that explains it a little better and in more details.

And here's a [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TLxxR/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `<div style="clear: both"></div>` after last `.child`.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the parent to display: inline-block and it will expand with the child.

```
#container {
  border:1px blue solid;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: But that will change how it behaves with other elements on the page.